# Помогите с чередованиями

Tags: орфоэпия, чередования

Нужно проверить чередование корней в слове **"берёт"** так, чтобы корень **бер** был ударным.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

В русском языке слова с чередующейся в корне гласной не проверяют ударением. Выбор гласной в таких корнях может зависеть от наличия в слове суффикса -а-, от ударения, от буквы, следующей за гласной, или от значения корня.

Так в словах с корнями бер-бир выбор гласной зависит от суффикса -а,
    есть суффикс а, пиши в корне и:  уб**е**ру — уб**и**р**а**ть. 
Такие корни следует знать наизусть, чтобы по ошибке не принять за слова с проверяемой гласной корня.

Answer (score 2):

Ирина, ударный вариант корня "бер" - "бор". Другого не бывает. 
Поэтому, чтобы проверить чередование, правильнее сказать - "наличие чередования", достаточно привести слова типа *наб**о**р*, 
*заб**о**р* и подобные, все они порождены этим корнем с чередованием "бор"/"бер".

Подобные чередования наблюдается как рефлекс различных древних процессов на месте исторического славянского "слогового р", которые в разных позиционных и семантических сочетаниях породили варианты: бр(ать),бер(ет), (на)бор (у некоторых слов этот список даже шире).

В отношении предлагаемых "отдельными авторами" слов на "-ирать",  надо понимать, что это немножко другой процесс, не имеющий отношения к ударной корневой гласной. Это типичный способ образования несовершенного вида от приставочных глаголов, он проявляется даже там, где никакого корневого чередования в обычном понимании и нету вовсе ("врать" - "привирать", "тереть" - "протирать"): глагольный суффикс как бы влезает в корень, инкапсулируется. Это происходит у огромного числа глаголов, не надо смешивать с истинным корневым чередованием,  на таких примерах вы ничего не проверите.